# Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker - Problem with TMPro with IL2CPP

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I have been trying for QUITE some time to migrate my project to newer versions of Unity, and to add the 64 bit support required in order to re-release my app for android.  After switching to IL@CPP, in order to target ARM64, I'm getting this error whenever I attempt to build:

```
Exception: Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\2020.3.34f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build/deploy/netcoreapp3.1/UnityLinker.exe @"C:/WC WS/WW3/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed/response.rsp"

stdout:
Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void TMPro.TMP_InputField::CreateCursorVerts()' in assembly: 'TextMeshPro-2017.3-Runtime.dll'
```

I have tried removing the TextMesh Pro folder, and reimporting TextMeshPro from the package manager.  I have looked to ensure no extra tmp/textmeshpro files exist.  So far, I cannot get through this error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was due to having installed an older TextMesh Pro version.  The Package Manager included the originally purchased version, along with the newer version, which was only visible once the "Unity Registry" packages were filtered in.  References to existing TextMeshPro objects had to be re-attached, but the CIL Linker error was resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).